# How to use PHP OPCache?

Tags: php, opcache

PHP 5.5 has been released and it features a new code caching module called OPCache, but there doesn't appear to be any documentation for it.

So where is the documentation for it and how do I use OPcache?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_5_5_s

Comment: Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php

Comment: Too bad that the Documentation does NOT tell us how to compile *opcache* correctly / disable it   nor workaround the autoconf of PHP 5.6.24+ source, so that PHP would compile! :-(

Comment: @Fred-ii- *"There are a lot of settings which may need adjusting. Understanding how it works and identifying issues during the stabilization phase of PHP 5.5 release process will greatly help."*... That blog post isn't very helpful. It doesn't explain how to understand how it works or how best to adjust the settings :(

Answer (score 379, accepted):

## Installation

OpCache is compiled by default on PHP5.5+. However it is disabled by default. In order to start using OpCache in PHP5.5+ you will first have to enable it. To do this you would have to do the following.

Add the following line to your `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/full/path/to/opcache.so (nix)
zend_extension=C:\path\to\php_opcache.dll (win)
```

Note that when the path contains spaces you should wrap it in quotes:

```
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP5.5\ext\php_opcache.dll"
```

Also note that you will have to use the `zend_extension` directive instead of the "normal" `extension` directive because it affects the actual Zend engine (i.e. the thing that runs PHP).

## Usage

Currently there are four functions which you can use:

#### [`opcache_get_configuration()`](http://php.net/opcache_get_configuration):

Returns an array containing the currently used configuration OpCache uses. This includes all ini settings as well as version information and blacklisted files.

```
var_dump(opcache_get_configuration());
```

#### [`opcache_get_status()`](http://php.net/opcache_get_status):

This will return an array with information about the current status of the cache. This information will include things like: the state the cache is in (enabled, restarting, full etc), the memory usage, hits, misses and some more useful information. It will also contain the cached scripts.

```
var_dump(opcache_get_status());
```

#### [`opcache_reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php):

Resets the entire cache. Meaning all possible cached scripts will be parsed again on the next visit.

```
opcache_reset();
```

#### [`opcache_invalidate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php):

Invalidates a specific cached script. Meaning the script will be parsed again on the next visit.

```
opcache_invalidate('/path/to/script/to/invalidate.php', true);
```

## Maintenance and reports

There are some GUI's created to help maintain OpCache and generate useful reports. These tools leverage the above functions.

***OpCacheGUI***

<sub>*Disclaimer I am the author of this project*</sub>

Features:

- OpCache status
- OpCache configuration
- OpCache statistics
- OpCache reset
- Cached scripts overview
- Cached scripts invalidation
- Multilingual
- Mobile device support
- Shiny graphs

Screenshots:

[image: status]

[image: cached-scripts]

[image: graphs]

[image: mobilr]

URL: https://github.com/PeeHaa/OpCacheGUI

***opcache-status***

Features:

- OpCache status
- OpCache configuration
- OpCache statistics
- Cached scripts overview
- Single file

Screenshot:

[image: status]

URL: https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status

***opcache-gui***

Features:

- OpCache status
- OpCache configuration
- OpCache statistics
- OpCache reset
- Cached scripts overview
- Cached scripts invalidation
- Automatic refresh

Screenshot:

[image: opcache-gui-overview]

URL: https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui

Comment: Anything in regard of PHP-CLI? How CLI utilizes it? When FPM restarted, OPCache resets - does it also affect CLI's OPCache? Is CLI's OPCache separate or does it share same Cache pool with FPM? Thanks!

Comment: OpCache was enabled by default for me on my most recent installation on ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.7, php 5.5.9.

Comment: hi, in your 3rd screenshot, cache_full is false, i am assuming its related to full page caching, could you please tell me how to turn it on? (make it true)

Comment: I am wrong, that is not for caching full page, but it will show up as true if the memory that the cache uses is full. Thanks anyways!

Comment: zend_extension=C:\path\to\php_opcache.dll (win) - Adding this line in php.ini works fine.

Comment: apaxhe can't find `zend_extension=C:\path\to\php_opcache.dll` buth the file is there, what's wrong?

Comment: Note that if you are using `Xdebug` extension, it MUST be loaded AFTER the `OpCache` extension.

Answer (score 153):

### OPcache replaces  APC

Because OPcache is designed to replace the APC module, it is not possible to run them in parallel in PHP. This is fine for caching PHP opcode as neither affects how you write code.

However it means that if you are currently using APC to store other data (through the [`apc_store()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) function) you will not be able to do that if you decide to use OPCache.

You will need to use another library such as either [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu) or [Yac](https://github.com/laruence/yac) which both store data in shared PHP memory, or switch to use something like memcached, which stores data in memory in a separate process to PHP.

Also, OPcache has no equivalent of the upload progress meter present in APC. Instead you should use the [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

### Settings for OPcache

The documentation for OPcache can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) with all of the configuration options listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php). The recommended settings are:

```lisp
; Sets how much memory to use
opcache.memory_consumption=128

;Sets how much memory should be used by OPcache for storing internal strings 
;(e.g. classnames and the files they are contained in)
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

; The maximum number of files OPcache will cache
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000

;How often (in seconds) to check file timestamps for changes to the shared
;memory storage allocation.
opcache.revalidate_freq=60

;If enabled, a fast shutdown sequence is used for the accelerated code
;The fast shutdown sequence doesn't free each allocated block, but lets
;the Zend Engine Memory Manager do the work.
opcache.fast_shutdown=1

;Enables the OPcache for the CLI version of PHP.
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

If you use any library or code that uses code annotations you must enable save comments:

```
opcache.save_comments=1
```

> If disabled, all PHPDoc comments are dropped from the code to reduce
> the size of the optimized code. Disabling "Doc Comments" may break
> some  existing applications and frameworks (e.g. Doctrine, ZF2,
> PHPUnit)

Comment: Found that link too, but I knew you'd dig a bit more ;-)

Comment: I'm going for the tag badge :)

Comment: There's a tag "badge"? ;-)

Comment: Are those recommended settings for production environments, for development, or both?

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding on my part of what exactly opcache is and what it is used for but I have it configured and tested with PeeHaa status script below. All is working. But I'm still asking the OP question. "How to use it?" It's not for caching views and things is it?

Comment: @isimmons "OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request."

Comment: Yep, just figured that out. Thought it's worth the comment because google led me here before I figured it out.

Comment: @marcvangend Good point ! I think caching makes only real sense in production, so these configs are probably production settings.

Comment: Can anyone explain why recommended settings performance is worse than default or when they should start giving effect?

Comment: `opcache.save_comments=1` has also to be set for Symfony2.

Comment: There is [an issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69190) where fast_shutdown causes segmentation faults (and therefore 500 errors) which means you may wish to set it to 0 until it is fixed.

Comment: Warning : don't enable OPcache if you use PHP in a chroot jail (shared hosting, for example) because of **security issue #69090** : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69090

Comment: Keep `opcache.fast_shutdown=0` untill this bug is fixed: http://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/146

Answer (score 21):

I am going to drop in my two cents for what I use opcache.

I have made an extensive framework with a lot of fields and validation methods and enums to be able to talk to my database.

**Without opcache**

When using this script without opcache and I push 9000 requests in 2.8 seconds to the apache server it maxes out at 90-100% cpu for 70-80 seconds until it catches up with all the requests.

`Total time taken: 76085 milliseconds(76 seconds)`

**With opcache enabled**

With opcache enabled it runs at 25-30% cpu time for about 25 seconds and never passes 25% cpu use.

`Total time taken: 26490 milliseconds(26 seconds)`

I have made an opcache blacklist file to disable the caching of everything except the framework which is all static and doesnt need changing of functionality. I choose explicitly for just the framework files so that I could develop without worrying about reloading/validating the cache files. Having everything cached saves a second on the total of the requests `25546 milliseconds`

This significantly expands the amount of data/requests I can handle per second without the server even breaking a sweat.

Comment: With "opcache enabled" means what configuration did you use to set it up?Only enabling it in the ini file or any other configuration is needed?

Comment: `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll; opcache.memory_consumption=128; opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8; opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000; opcache.revalidate_freq=60;
opcache.fast_shutdown=1; opcache.enable_cli=1; opcache.blacklist_filename="C:\xampp\php\cfg\opcache.blacklist;`
Just replace the ; with an enter in the ini file. But this is what I used. mostly default stuff

Comment: btw, me running this with memcache doing 2100 database requests a second runs the script I use within 150 microseconds(about 1/6th of a millisecond)

Comment: that will help me in going ahead though I dont use memcache right now,I believe opcache can help on the PHP front.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Opcache caches the php files in compiled form in memory. So you don't have overhead of reading from disk and compiling & optimizing of files by the php parser anymore. Memcache is something you can use to store variables in between sessions. Sayt for example a user has an update script that requests the same parameters for 10 seconds whilst user stares at ascreen. You could use mem cache to compile the query once, and then keep requesting the compiled query from memory isntead of regenerating it.

Comment: Thank you for the above info!And does opcache check each time if the php files are updated?I mean how does it come to know about the files are updated and need to be recompiled?

Comment: it doesn't. `opcache.revalidate_freq=60;` determines how long a file may live in memory in seconds. when the time is up it recompiles the file.

Comment: Great info!!I will add comments in case I get stuck at any point! :P

Comment: Actually, `opcache.revalidate_freq` controls how often a script is checked for changes (based on whether its timestamp changed). So if a script's timestamp remains the same as the last time it was compiled, it won't be recompiled. All of this is assuming you haven't changed the `opcache.validate_timestamps` setting, which is enabled by default.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying that. I assumed there would be a rudementary check like that

Comment: @jjlin - When you say it won't be recompiled, do you mean it remains in memory indefinitely or until PHP or the web server is restarted? Second, if `opcache.validate_timestamps` is enabled by default i.e.`opcache.validate_timestamps=1`, do you mean that `opcache.revalidate_freq` only validates if the timestamp has changed every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

With PHP 5.6 on Amazon Linux (should be the same on RedHat or CentOS):

```
yum install php56-opcache
```

and then restart apache.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this when setting up moodle.
I added the following lines in the php.ini file.

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll

[opcache]
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 4000
opcache.revalidate_freq = 60

; Required for Moodle
opcache.use_cwd = 1
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.save_comments = 1
opcache.enable_file_override = 0

; If something does not work in Moodle
;opcache.revalidate_path = 1 ; May fix problems with include paths
;opcache.mmap_base = 0x20000000 ; (Windows only) fix OPcache crashes with event id 487

; Experimental for Moodle 2.6 and later
;opcache.fast_shutdown = 1
;opcache.enable_cli = 1 ; Speeds up CLI cron
;opcache.load_comments = 0 ; May lower memory use, might not be compatible with add-ons and other apps

extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll

[intl]
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

intl -> http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Comment: Might be worth noting that this settings are documented here: https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/OPcache

Comment: `opcache.fast_shutdown = 0` http://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/146