# PHP 5.5 OPCache not working on apache

Tags: php, apache, opcache

I'm in charge of the opcode cache exchange here in my company, we're moving from eaccelerator to the Zend OPCache shipped with PHP 5.5.

When I access PHP in CLI, it seems like the OPCache is working fine:

```
PHP 5.5.5 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2013 10:29:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I access my website via Apache, the benchmarks show no improvements compared to the same pages using no opcode cache. Also, `get_loaded_extensions(true)` returns an empty array.

Can anyone answer me why on earth it isn't working?

I'm using windows 7, Apache 2.4.6 from Apache Lounge, PHP 5.5.5 from windows.php.net.

---

EDIT:

As requested, my OPCache configuration:

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
;opcache.use_cwd=1
;opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;opcache.revalidate_path=0
;opcache.save_comments=1
;opcache.load_comments=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;opcache.enable_file_override=0
;opcache.optimization_level=0xffffffff
;opcache.inherited_hack=1
;opcache.dups_fix=0
;opcache.blacklist_filename=
;opcache.max_file_size=0
;opcache.consistency_checks=0
;opcache.force_restart_timeout=180
;opcache.error_log=
;opcache.log_verbosity_level=1
;opcache.preferred_memory_model=
;opcache.protect_memory=0
```

Comment: Can you provide us the phpinfo's opcache section?

Comment: Of course, I just put in the question's description.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PHP OPCache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer!

`zend_extension` extensions must set the complete path, not a relative one.

In this case, `zend_extension="C:\Apache24\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"` solved my problems.

Comment: In my case changing `extension=php_opcache.dll` to `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll` helped.

Comment: zend_extension=php_opcache.dll (Plus the default settings opcache.enable = 1...) Worked for me.

Comment: for UwAmp:  `zend_extension={PHPEXTPATH}/php_opcache.dll`

Answer (score 5):

### WINDOWS PHP 7 SOLUTION

By default there are opcache settings in php.ini files like opcache.eneable but enabling opcache does not take effect unless you add:

```
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
```

to your config file. **Remember it is zend_extension and not regular exstension !**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have "opcache" in your phpinfo(); report. [By default](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php):

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the [building on Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php) section.

Can you confirm that the extension is loaded?

Comment: No, it wasn't showing in my `phpinfo()` as well. But, as I mentioned before, i was specifying the wrong path for the extension.