# I am seeing old laravel site even after updating files

Tags: laravel

I have a website that uses vuejs as frontend and Laravel API in backend. Recently I updated my Laravel site it was working absolutely fine in my localhost. But the problem is when I upload my Laravel files to my hostinger.com hosting account it's not updating. It's displaying me old site but my database got updated and I was able to errors of the new site.

I tried these none of them seems to be working,

1. Cleared browser history and cache
2. Tried reuploading site again
3. I ran following commands

`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan route:cache`
`php artisan view:cache`
`npm run prod`

4. Tried to use cmd command `ipconfig/flushdns`

Still, I was not able to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using OPCache ? Might be worth checking and clearing the opcache cache if yes

Comment: But I have not installed any package called 'opcache'

Comment: OPCache It is not a "package", it is a PHP extension. Check if it is enabled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773041/is-my-opcache-running

Comment: I checked my hosting account in PHP configuration it is disabled already.

Comment: But its enabled in my localhost

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing your website with `CTRL+F5` or `CTRL+R` ?