# Was a script hit by opCache or no?

Tags: php, opcache

Is it possible to tell from inside of PHP whether a script was hit by opCache or no.

I know that I can find out some statistics from `phpinfo()` about the number of

- Cache hits
- Cache misses
- Cached scripts
- Cached keys

The problem is that this is just statistics. What I want is to do the following. When I run some script `test.php` from inside script it would tell me whether it was hit or missed by opCache. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Quite a bit of info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17304671/2518525

Comment: @Darren thank you, but I already read a lot of docs about opCache, and this post as well.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, the answer is contained there - please go read the [`opcache_get_status` page in the manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php).  Look at the argument list in specific.