# how to check if the file is uploaded already in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

i have to upload a file and insert the data into tables.i am done with that part.
now,i want to check whether the file has been already uploaded or not. if so,alert should be thrown.

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    if($_FILES['file']['name'])
    {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $a=$filename[0];
        foreach($a as $b){
        if($b==$filename[0]){
                            echo"file already uploaded";
                            }
                          }
     }
   }
```

Comment: It is not clear what your actual problem is. Please elaborate.

Comment: @yakobom i sholud not upload the file which is already been uploaded.

Comment: are you encrypting a name while uploding?  @dodo

Comment: @ankitsuthar no am just want to check if the file's records has already been inserted into the database or not

Comment: see this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939712/file-exists-not-working-codeigniter) may be it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             if($filename[1] == 'csv')
                                    {

                                         $fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
                                         $a=$filename[0];
                                         echo $a;
                                         $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * from table WHERE table.filename='".$a."'");
                                         $b=$query1->num_rows();
                                         if($b>0)

                                         {
                                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('FILE ALREADY BEEN UPLOADED')</script>";
                                         }
              else{
                  }
```

Comment: i did add a column filename to the table where the records being uploaded.