# How to integrate OpCache with Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.5, opcache, symfony-2.6

I am new to symfony. I want to integrate OpCache with symfony2. I have no idea that how can I do this. If have any idea please let me know the steps what should I do.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

OpCache is the cache for OpCodes. It is just enabled or disabled. There is no integration needed at all.

If you want to use user-cache you should use some other cache-system or use APCu that will provide you user-cache functionality through APC compatible functions.

Then you can just setup Doctrine to use APC as cache engine. But in your application you will need manually manage your cache.