# Do function results in PHP get cached?

Tags: php, performance, caching

Are the results of functions being cached internally by PHP?

Simple example:

```
public function calc($arg){
  return pow($arg,0.5);
}

echo calc(5) . "<br>";
echo calc(5) . "<br>";
```

Will PHP caculate calc() twice, or will it recognize that the argument hasn't changed and give me some kind of cached result?

Comment: Yes `PHP` will calculate it twice.

Comment: No, PHP doesn't optimize like this..... it will get executed twice.... caching function results would be very bad if your function was something like: `public function calc($arg){ static $i = 0.5;
  return pow($arg,$i++);
}` or accessed class properties that could have been changed between calls to the method

Comment: wouldn't that be an implementation detail, left to whoever writes the interpreter?

Comment: For this type of requirement we have if else conditions call function only when the argument is not same

Comment: So basically, you're asking if php does memoization out of the box - as per comments of other developers - it doesn't do that out of the box so you will need to write that part yourself, in case you need it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [opcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache/17304671#17304671) installed then PHP will cache the *operational code*, or opcode. These are the machine level instructions that PHP runs. In other words, PHP is caching how to run your function, not the results or the output of running it with a given data set.

If you want to save the value of your run, you should store the result in a variable and reference that instead of calling the function over and over

```
$data = calc(5);
```