# Speedup REST API Service Laravel 5

Tags: php, performance, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1 to make a REST API service, and i would like to lower the response time of the API.
There is somes solution to lower API response except the serveur performance ?
Actually the serveur respond in **250 ms**. (In production)
My old API on Slim Framework responded in **170 ms**.

Thank's.

Comment: First of all, you should enable opcache. Find a tutorial depending on which webserver (apache/nginx) you're using for that project.

Comment: you're welcome. Let me know in comments results after enabling opcache.

Comment: @limonte The serveur respond in 370ms the first call and 100 ms all the orther next call !

Comment: great! I'll pop my comment into an answer then so this question can be marked answered and removed from unanswered lists.

Comment: Ok, but do you know why the fist call is too long?

Comment: Haven't you considered using [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) instead of Laravel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First step of PHP optimization is enabling a bytecode cache engine [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php).

As each PHP script is being compiled at runtime, a part of the execution time gets used for transforming the human readable code into code that can be understood by the machine.

A bytecode cache engine does it only once – during the first execution of a specific PHP file. Then the precompiled script is being stored in memory, which should lead to performance boosts in your PHP applications.

That is the reason why you have 300ms response time for the first request, and 100ms for all other requests.

Understanding OPcache: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-opcache/

Enabling OPcache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17304671/1331425

PS. There's a nice dashboard for monitoring memory consumption - [OPcache Dashboard](https://github.com/carlosbuenosvinos/opcache-dashboard):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One of the solution is to **update your PHP version to PHP7**

As per [Rasmus Lerdorf presentation](http://talks.php.net/oz15#/geeklogbench), the greatest part about PHP 7 is the incredible performance boosts it provides to applications. This is a result of refactoring the Zend Engine to use more compact data structures and less heap allocations/deallocations.

[image]

https://github.com/php/php-src/releases

https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference#performance