# How to enable PHP OPcode caching for Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, xampp, drupal-8

I want to enable PHP OPcode caching for Drupal 8 installation. I have the following in Xampp **php.ini**. However, I still get opcode not enabled. What am I doing wrong??

```
opcache.enable=1

engine = On
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll


opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Comment: What is your `extension_dir` value in your `php.ini`? and where does `php_opcache.dll` reside?

Comment: Is there an error message regarding the `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll` line in the error logs? If not, it is likely that the extension was loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hello Universe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887791/hello-universe) see if this helps :-

- Try to use `zend_extension=opcache` instead of `zend_extension=php_opcache.dll` as the former has been deprecated in PHP major version. Check your [php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B5JU.png) file for more details.
- Check if [zend.assertions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.assertions)! are enabled.
- I would recommend to go through [Opcache issue solved](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-03-03/drupal-8-opcache-warning-php-opcode-caching-not-enabled#comment-11789022)! , which is working fine for most of the cases.
- Restart your Apache.

Answer (score 4):

Here is nice post about OPCache:
[How to use PHP OPCache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache)

And here is for localhost with XAMPP:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2623566

Comment: And here is for localhost with XAMPP: https://www.drupal.org/node/2623566
. This one worked for me. Lubos @thank you

Answer (score 2):

First of all check your PHP version. Before and after PHP 5.5 things are little bit different. You may refer for difference here http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php

Also if you are using zend extension then full path of dll is required in below

zend_extension=/your/path/tod/dll/php_opcache.dll

Also make sure to use correct one in terms of threaded or non threaded version.

Answer (score 1):

Open php.ini file.
There You have to uncomment this line of code: zend_extension=opcache.so . After that restart lampp/xampp. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

change your **php.ini** config:

```
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[opcache] zend_extension=php_opcache.dll 
;Determines if Zend OPCache in enabled 
opcache.enable=1 
opcache.memory_consumption=128 
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8 
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000 
opcache.revalidate_freq=60 
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Paste this link in php.ini

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Users
Go in /Application/XAMPP/etc/php.ini line no.

Change this

```
;zend_extension=opcache.so
```

to (remove ;)

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
```

Save the file php.ini and restart the server.