# Use uncached / uncompiled laravel blade template

Tags: view, laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible to use an uncompiled / uncached laravel blade view so that a stack trace doesn't report :

C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\views\952767ebe8bae04dc9f53b45e5aa8047

but rather the original name :

C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\view.blade.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579182/laravel-and-view-caching-in-development-cant-see-changes-right-away

Answer (score 0):

View cache is in the core of Laravel's View, I don't think you can do that easily, but, in a quick dirty look at this, you can delete your remaining views every time your application starts, as you won't have many of them around, this should be fast.

```php
foreach(File::files(App::make('path.storage').'/views') as $file) 
{
    File::delete($file);
}
```