# Laravel FTP upload shows older version

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

This is the first time I encounter this problem, I upload all contents to my FTP ( already tried erasing everything ) And I always see an older version..

When I run a server using

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Everything is correct, but on the testing server it's still an older version.

Any idea what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you're uploading it to the correct place on the remote server? Is this shared hosting, or is it a VPS?

Comment: It's a subsite ( as a staging server ).. and it's the right one, because if i erase it there's nothing left to see and i get a 404. thank you

Comment: Well, so much for an easy solution ;) If you're using PHP 5.5, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623382/899126) might be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as this is a shared hosting I don't believe we have access to the php.ini, any method around this?

Comment: Shared hosting...hm. It depends on the hosting provider, but you might check your cPanel to see if you can change your php.ini file. Some place it in your home directory or in your public_html directory, but that's up to them. The best course of action, unfortunately, might be to contact them for support. Another alternative is to, depending on your comfort with Linux, run a VPS through DigitalOcean ([referral link](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=3cd6ca859d5d), [non-referral link](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/registrations/new)) so that you can control your environment.