# local Laravel web page takes several minutes to update

Tags: php, apache, laravel, google-chrome

I am running an apache server locally and building a web service in Laravel. Yesterday, my local Laravel webpage was very responsive, reflecting any changes made as soon as I saved and refreshed. Today it is taking upwards of 5 minutes for the page to update. I have not changed my code since yesterday. A couple of interesting tidbits...

-I am running the page in Chrome and have disabled caching

-My system clock is set to the correct time

-I have run php artisan clear:compiled with no success

-I have manually deleted cached views in my storage->views folder

-If I send a POST request to my web service with postman, any changes will still take a few minutes to apply

I know this is not a lot to go off of, but I am totally stumped and this is sapping my productivity! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything in Apache/PHP logs?

Comment: No, nothing that I can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, I fixed this by disabling caching in my php.ini file and restarting my server [(see this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579182/laravel-and-view-caching-in-development-cant-see-changes-right-away) why this became an issue out of the blue after several weeks, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have cache disabled in Chrome, I would still do a hard reload. I would also run the following:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

to clear the cache, not needed in dev env, imo.

Comment: I tried using artisan to clear my cache and routes, per your recommendation, but the problem still persists. Any other ideas?