# Why custom directive not reflecting changes in its code immediately

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, templating

I am writing a simple custom directive in Laravel. Whenever I make some changes in the code of custom directive, its not reflected in the view until I

- Comment the directive in view.
- Reload the page
- Uncomment the directive
- Reload the page to finally get the changes

**Custom directive code in global.php**

```
Blade::extend(function($value, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('molvi');
    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo ucwords($2); ?>', $value);
});
```

**Directive call in view**

```
@molvi('haji') //this will output 'Haji' due to ucwords($2)

//the ucwords() is replaced with strtolower()
@molvi('haji') //this will still output 'Haji'
```

I am converting the words to uppercase. When lets say I want to use `strtolower()` instead of `ucwords()`, I have to repeat above steps to get changes reflected.

**UPDATE**

I have tried to clear the cache with various methods as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971445/how-i-can-disable-templates-caching-in-development-mode) but still no success.

**UPDATE**

Since no one is answering this question on StackOverFlow, I have posted it on [laravel github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9732).

Comment: Probably because of the cache. [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971445/how-i-can-disable-templates-caching-in-development-mode).

Comment: I have added the code provided in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18102850/3131443 in filters.php but still getting this issue

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me understand this problem. I got no answer still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I am just pasting the answer given by @lukasgeiter on [github thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9732).

> The problem is that the compiled views are cached and you can't
>   disable that. You can however clear the files. Either manually by
>   deleting everything in storage/framework/views or by running the
>   command `php artisan view:clear`

**Not supported in Laravel 4 or 5.0**

This command is not found in Laravel 4 or 5.0. Its a new command and introduced in Larvel 5.1. Here is the [ViewClearCommand](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ViewClearCommand.php) code from 5.1.

**Manually add support in Laravel 4 or 5.0**

You can manually add support in Laravel 4 or 5.0.

**Register new command**

The way to achieve it in previous versions is to register new command. The [Aritsan Development](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#introduction) section is helpful in this regard.

**Final working code for 4.2.1**

I have tested the following code on 4.2.1.

**Add new command file**

app/commands/ClearViewCommmand.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class ClearViewCommand extends Command {
/**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'view:clear';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Clear all compiled view files';

protected $files;
/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Filesystem $files)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->files = $files;
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
    //this path may be different for 5.0
    $views = $this->files->glob(storage_path().'/views/*');
    foreach ($views as $view) {
        $this->files->delete($view);
    }
    $this->info('Compiled views cleared!');
}

}
```

**Register new command**

Add the following line in app/start/artisan.php

```
Artisan::resolve('ClearViewCommand');
```

**CLI**

Now finally you can run the command. After each update of code in custom directive you can run this command to get immediate changes in views.

```
php artisan view:clear
```